# MCP4822 DAC SPI protocol

Tags: spi, dac

I have here a problem with controlling the DAC MCP4822 over SPI. In the
datasheet (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002249B.pdf) is no address stated, which is needed for the SPI protocol. Does anyone know how I can set the register in the MCP4822? I already tried directly to send the data instead an address, but also this lead to no success.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up SPI with I²C

Comment: SPI does not use addresses. This chip uses chipselect lines and configuration bits. See section 5.2

Comment: Which part of section 5 (pages 21-23) is not clear? All of the details seem to be there.

Comment: SPI protocol does not have an address field. Please read carefully p. 22 and 23.

Comment: Ok, ye you are right, I only used the addresses for the RAM, which I sent over SPI, but I sent them as data, I got confused. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

> no address stated, which is needed for the SPI protocol

No, SPI doesn't use addresses.  It is a serial protocol with one clock line, and one data line for each direction.  The master controls the clock (SCK).  Data is transferred from the master to the slave on the MOSI (master out slave in) line, and from slave to master on the MISO line.

All devices are connected to these three lines.  At most one slave device at a time is enabled with its own chip enable line.  This is typically a negative logic signal, meaning the master pulls it low to active the corresponding slave.  There is a separate chip select line for each slave.

No addresses are abused in the making of a SPI bus.